# Template Specialization - Too Few Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

So I was playing around with template specialization and ran across an issue. I was looking at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) while writing the below code.

I cut it down but basically I am doing something incorrectly with the templates for calc and I'm not sure what. From all the other posts I've seen people are forgetting "template<>" before their specialized classes, but I don't think that is what is causing my issue. Any suggestions?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, bool isDouble = std::is_same<T, double>::value>
struct precision
{ 
    typedef T p_type;
    /* some stuff here*/
};

template <typename T>
struct precision<T, false>
{ 
    typedef T p_type;
    /* some stuff here*/
};

template <typename P>
struct is_double
{ 
    static const bool value = std::is_same< typename P::p_type, double >::value;
};

template <typename T, typename SP, typename DP>
struct calc
{
    static_assert(!is_double<SP>::value, "SP is not single precision");
    static_assert(is_double<DP>::value, "DP is not double precision");
};

template <typename T, typename SP>
struct calc<T, SP, precision<double>>
{
    static_assert(!is_double<SP>::value, "SP is not single precision");
};

template <typename T, typename DP>
struct calc<T, precision<float>, DP>
{
    static_assert(is_double<DP>::value, "DP is not double precision");
};

template <typename T>
struct calc<T, precision<float>, precision<double>>
{ };

int main()
{
    calc<int> t1; //"too few template arguments"
    calc<int, precision<double> > t2; //"too few template arguments"
    calc<int, precision<float> > t3; //"too few template arguments"
    calc<int, precision<float>, precision<double>> t4;
}
```

Comment: The error is just what it says: `calc` always has three template parameters, and none of them have default arguments.  In `main` you are giving it fewer than three template arguments.

Comment: This is the normal behaviour, it fails to match any of the specializations and matches `template <typename T, typename SP, typename DP> struct calc`, which apparently needs 3 arguments. What did you expected? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing specializations for the implementation, but you seem to expect that this also provides default values for the template parameters of the main template. This is not true.

To provide defaults, try:

```
template <typename T, typename SP = precision<float>, typename DP = precision<double>>
struct calc
{
    static_assert(!is_double<SP>::value, "SP is not single precision");
    static_assert(is_double<DP>::value, "DP is not double precision");
};
```

and leave the rest of the code (including the specializations) as it is. See what parts of your code will react in which way to the change, but note that this will not fix all of your problems. It is just meant to help you understand that you are mixing/confusing two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the template for `calc` with 3 arguments, but did not use all of those arguments for the first three variable declarations in your `main()`.